# Що означає "не на часі"?

Tags: росіянізм, словосполучення, калька

[Прочитала статтю](https://zaxid.net/ne_na_chasi_n1112832)

В ній часто звучить вислів "не на часі", стало цікаво, що він означає
Знайшла в Вікіпедії приклад

[Вікісловник](https://uk.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%96)

> - підходящий, необхідний у даний момент; вчасний
>
> Не знаю, що й сказати..— мовила Тетяна, поглядаючи на матір.— Трохи ніби твоє освідчення несподіване… і *не на часі* (С. Добровольський)
>
> Я відчував, що позбавляюсь сил. Вага одежі й Жабі тягли мене наспід, під лід. І допомога Михайлова якраз була *на часі*. (Олесь Досвітній)

Ніби зрозуміло, але потім зустрічаю статтю, де вказано, що "не на часі" - це калька.

[Газета по-українськи](https://gazeta.ua/articles/chistota-movlennya/_ak-i-hto-maye-navesti-lad-u-pravilah-suchasnoyi-ukrayinskoyi-movi/582784)

> Але ж начебто ніщо й ніхто не заважає позбутися тепер цього мовного сміття. Чи щось таки заважає?
> Може, лінощі ("та то таке", *"не на часі"* тощо)? Чи та ж звичка ("може, й неправильно, але вже загальноприйнято")?

То чи можна вживати такий вираз?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Поґуґлимо саме цей вираз українською мовою.](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%22%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%96%22&source=lnt&tbs=lr:lang_1uk&lr=lang_uk&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiVrcvxvunZAhXI_qQKHYxcDSIQpwUIHw&biw=1366&bih=662)

Видає 60 100 результатів.

До того ж, знаходимо статтю [Тараса Прохаська](https://zbruc.eu/node/61816) саме з такою назвою, а Прохаська складно запідозрити у неосвіченості або бажанні користуватися калькованими виразами.

До того ж, у статті, на яку ви посилаєтесь, автор, думаю, не має на увазі, що "не на часі" - скалькований вираз:

> Може, лінощі ("та то таке", "не на часі" тощо)? Чи та ж звичка ("може,
>   й неправильно, але вже загальноприйнято")?

Як на мене, це просто цитування пояснень людей, які не хочуть позбавлятися росіянізмів у своєму мовленні.

Answer (score 4):

Стаття СУМ на іменник [**ЧАС**](http://sum.in.ua/s/chas) пропонує і *на часі*, й *не на часі*:

> **На часі**:
>
> а) саме в пору, у необхідний момент; вчасно. Я відчував, що
>   позбавляюсь сил. Вага одежі й Жабі тягли мене наспід, під лід. І
>   допомога Михайлова якраз була *на часі* (Олесь Досвітній, Вибр., 1959,
>   183); — Не знаю, що й сказати... — мовила Тетяна, поглядаючи на матір.
>   — Трохи ніби твоє освідчення несподіване... і *не на часі* (Спиридон
>   Добровольський, Тече річка.., 1961, 226);
>
> б) на черзі дня. — Колгоспи *на часі*, щасливе життя зазирає до нас у
>   шибки, стукотить майбутнє в двері... (Юрій Яновський, I, 1954, 119);
>   Уже давно *на часі* синтетичне дослідження про Григорія Тютюнника —
>   письменника пластичного, сильного письма, творця глибоких національно
>   виразних характерів (Радянське літературознавство, 1, 1969, 34);

Не бачу застережень щодо вживання.