# Синоніми до словосполучення "на часі"

Tags: синоніми

На сайті є питання ["Що означає "не на часі"?"](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/3280/%D0%A9%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%94-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%96/5523#5523)

Мене ж цікавить чи є синоніми до словосполучення "на часі".

В СУМ-11 стаття "час" подає таке визначення

> На часі: а) саме в пору, у необхідний момент; вчасно.

Слово "вчасно" буде повним синонімов до "на часі"? Які ще є синоніми до "на часі"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Згідно до [Практичного словника синонімів української мови](http://shron1.chtyvo.org.ua/Karavanskyy_Sviatoslav/Praktychnyi_slovnyk_synonimiv_ukrainskoi_movy.pdf) (ст. 8), синонімами можуть бути:

> Своєчасний, актуальний

Згідно до [фразеологічного словника](https://supermif.com/frazeologizm/nnn.html):

> необхідний у даний момент; вчасний; важливий для даного часу; який
>   відповідає найважливішим потребам сучасності.

Згідно до [Вікісловника](https://uk.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%96#%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%B8), його можна замінити словосполученнями:

> підходящий, необхідний у даний момент; вчасний
>
> важливий для сучасного періоду; який відповідає найважливішим потребам
>   сьогодення